# IBM MFP7.1 Hybrid iOS application gets rejected by Apple Store, How to fix this?

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, mfp

I am building application with xCode10.1 and when I submitted application for App store it gets rejected..and the reason for rejection is Invalid Architectures..

Dev Environment:
IBM MFP7.1 - Hybrid Application

I had removed i386 and *86_64 from valid architectures in build setting options but did not worked..attached build settings screenshot. please advice

[image]

Comment: This blog might help you https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/10/17/prepare-ios-apps-for-app-store-submission/

Comment: I see you using arm64e in debug? Can you paste "lipo -info" output of your binaries ? Sometimes Invalid architecture warning from app store are misleading, if possible you can paste a detailed rejection information here if something or check something else is also relevant?